# Android 4.0: canvas.setViewport error

Tags: android

I'm getting an error in my code. 
the method setViewPort(int, int) cannot be defined for the type canvas.

I am trying to implement multi touch functionality on an ImageView, the intire class is far too long to put up here but if you require more information just comment.

```
    @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            if(layout) {
                if(!viewSet) {
//line that's causing issue                 
canvas.setViewport(displayWidth, displayHeight);
                    viewSet = true;
                }
```

can't figure out what the issue is, have all necessary imports etc.

Would it be the fact I'm using Android 4.0?

thanks.

Shaw

Comment: Same here, looking at the documentation, the method isn't mentioned anymore nor marked as deprecated. I used the method before on earlier SDKs version <4, but with SDK 4, the method isn't found anymore.

Comment: I also posted the question in the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/opNpb3qKauE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer from Romain Guy from the Google Group:

> "This method was removed because it had no effect whatsoever. It was a
>   remnant of an old and failed experiment."